# jQuery .load() call doesn't execute JavaScript in loaded HTML file

Tags: jquery, ajax, safari

This seems to be a problem related to Safari only.  I've tried 4 on Mac and 3 on Windows and am still having no luck.

I'm trying to load an external HTML file and have the JavaScript that is embedded execute.

The code I'm trying to use is this:

```
$("#myBtn").click(function() {
    $("#myDiv").load("trackingCode.html");
});
```

`trackingCode.html` looks like this (simple now, but will expand once/if I get this working):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tracking HTML File</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert("outside the jQuery ready");
        $(function() {
            alert("inside the jQuery ready");
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm seeing both alert messages in IE (6 & 7) and Firefox (2 & 3). However, I am not able to see the messages in Safari (the last browser that I need to be concerned with - project requirements - please no flame wars).

Any thoughts on why Safari is ignoring the JavaScript in the `trackingCode.html` file?

Eventually I'd like to be able to pass JavaScript objects to this `trackingCode.html` file to be used within the jQuery ready call, but I'd like to make sure this is possible in all browsers before I go down that road.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You are loading an entire HTML page into your div, including the html, head and body tags.  What happens if you do the load and just have the opening script, closing script, and JavaScript code in the HTML that you load?

Here is the driver page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>jQuery Load of Script</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#myButton").click(function() {
                    $("#myDiv").load("trackingCode.html");
                });
             });
         </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="myButton">Click Me</button>
        <div id="myDiv"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the contents of trackingCode.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Outside the jQuery ready");
    $(function() {
        alert("Inside the jQuery ready");
    });
 </script>
```

This works for me in Safari 4.

Update: Added DOCTYPE and html namespace to match the code on my test environment.  Tested with Firefox 3.6.13 and example code works.

Comment: Got it, thanks Tony!  Removing the <html>, <head> and <body> tags seemed to do the trick.

Comment: i was wandering whether i should do a seperate ajax call getJson() because i heard of this.. But if it works like that it is ok!! I would call the same queries twice otherwise

Comment: Your code is not actually working in FF (IE8 - working fine).
Is there a way to make this work in **all** the browsers?

Thanks

Comment: @Maxim Galushka I still had these files in my personal workstation.  Without modification, they produced the correct behavior.  I am using Firefox 3.6.13 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 44):

```
$("#images").load(location.href+" #images",function(){
    $.getScript("js/productHelper.js"); 
});
```

Comment: This did the trick for me. Here is an example that you can try:
var frmAcademicCalendar = "frmAcademicCalendar.aspx"
if (window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf(frmAcademicCalendar.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
          $("#IncludeCMSContent").load("http://www.example.com #externalContent",function() {
      $.getScript("example.js"); 
  });
}

Answer (score 25):

A other version of [John Pick's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889967/jquery-load-call-doesnt-execute-javascript-in-loaded-html-file/7251380#7251380) just before, this works fine for me :

```
jQuery.ajax({
   ....
   success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
       jQuery(selecteur).html(jqXHR.responseText);
       var reponse = jQuery(jqXHR.responseText);
       var reponseScript = reponse.filter("script");
       jQuery.each(reponseScript, function(idx, val) { eval(val.text); } );
   }
   ...
});
```

Comment: This is the best solution!, I love you @Yannick, you made my day

Answer (score 15):

I realize this is somewhat of an older post, but for anyone that comes to this page looking for a similar solution...

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

> ```
> jQuery.getScript( url, [ success(data, textStatus) ] )
> ```
>
> - *`url`* - A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.
> - *`success(data, textStatus)`* - A callback function that is executed if the request succeeds.
>
> ```
> $.getScript('ajax/test.js', function() {
>   alert('Load was performed.');
> });
> ```

Answer (score 11):

This doesn't seem to work if you're loading the HTML field into a dynamically created element.

```
$('body').append('<div id="loader"></div>');
$('#loader').load('htmlwithscript.htm');
```

I look at firebug DOM and there is no script node at all, only the HTML and my CSS node.

Anyone have come across this?

Comment: I had to load the html, then in the callback, use $.getScript to get the javascript.

Comment: Dude! You solved my problem about 8 years earlier. Thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

Test with this in trackingCode.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

       show_alert();

       function show_alert() {
           alert("Inside the jQuery ready");
       }

    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I wrote the following jquery plugin for html loading function: [http://webtech-training.blogspot.in/2010/10/dyamic-html-loader.html](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:X2zk3N56u6YJ:webtech-training.blogspot.in/2010/10/dyamic-html-loader.html%20&cd=1&hl=hu&ct=clnk&gl=ro#!http://webtech-training.blogspot.com/2010/10/dyamic-html-loader.html)

Answer (score 3):

You've almost got it. Tell jquery you want to load only the script:

```
$("#myBtn").click(function() {
    $("#myDiv").load("trackingCode.html script");
});
```

Comment: But this seems to ONLY load and the script. How do you get it to load the html content AND run any javascript it might contain?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this where the scripts would load once, but repeat calls would not run the script.

It turned out to be an issue with using .html() to display a wait indicator and then chaining .load() after it.

```
// Processes scripts as expected once per page load, but not for repeat calls
$("#id").html("<img src=wait.gif>").load("page.html");
```

When I made them separate calls, my inline scripts loaded every time as expected.

```
// Without chaining html and load together, scripts are processed as expected every time
$("#id").html("<img src=wait.gif>");
$("#id").load("page.html");
```

For further research, note that there are two versions of .load()

A simple .load() call (without a selector after the url) is simply a shorthand for calling $.ajax() with dataType:"html" and taking the return contents and calling .html() to put those contents in the DOM.  And the documentation for dataType:"html" clearly states "included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM." http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/  So .load() officially runs inline scripts.

A complex .load() call has a selector such as load("page.html #content").  When used that way, jQuery purposefully filters out script tags as discussed in articles like this one: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/the-load-function-and-script-blocks#14737000000752785  In this case the scripts never run, not even once.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load both the HTML and scripts, here's a more automated way to do so utilizing both `$(selector).load()` and `jQuery.getScript()`. This specific example loads the HTML content of the element with ID "toLoad" from `content.html`, inserts the HTML into the element with ID "content", and then loads and runs all scripts within the element with the "toLoad" ID.

```
$("#content").load("content.html #toLoad", function(data) {
    var scripts = $(data).find("script");

    if (scripts.length) {
        $(scripts).each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr("src")) {
                $.getScript($(this).attr("src"));
            }
            else {
                eval($(this).html());
            }
        });
    }

});
```

This code finds all of the script elements in the content that is being loaded, and loops through each of these elements. If the element has a `src` attribute, meaning it is a script from an external file, we use the `jQuery.getScript` method of fetching and running the script. If the element does not have a `src` attribute, meaning it is an inline script, we simply use `eval` to run the code. If it finds no script elements, it solely inserts the HTML into the target element and does not attempt to load any scripts.

I've tested this method in Chrome and it works. Remember to be cautious when using `eval`, as it can run potentially unsafe scripts and is generally considered harmful. You might want to avoid using inline scripts when using this method in order to avoid having to use `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

Well I had the same problem that only seemed to happen for Firefox, and I couldn't use another JQuery command except for .load() since I was modifying the front-end on exisitng PHP files...

Anyways, after using the .load() command, I embedded my JQuery script within the external HTML that was getting loaded in, and it seemed to work. I don't understand why the JS that I loaded at the top of the main document didn't work for the new content however...

Comment: Easy, because the new content was not there when the script got executed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by changing `$(document).ready()` to `window.onLoad()`.

Answer (score 0):

Tacking onto @efreed answer...

I was using `.load('mypage.html #theSelectorIwanted')` to call content from a page by selector, but that means it does not execute the inline scripts inside.

Instead, I was able to change my markup so that `'#theSelectorIwanted'`became it's own file and I used

```
load('theSelectorIwanted.html`, function() {});
```

and it ran the inline scripts just fine.

Not everyone has that option but this was a quick workaround to get where I wanted!