# Why doesn't my jQquery script work when loaded into another page?

Tags: jquery

I have this code working perfectly fine on a page:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
  ThumbnailScroller("tsv_container","vertical",40,800,"easeOutCirc",0.4,500);
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.thumbnailScroller.js"></script>
```

It doesn't however work, when i load this page into a div on another page.

I tried putting this code on the parent page with the div, but it still doesn't work. Can anyone tell me how to fix it so that the code runs on the parent page?

Comment: For one thing I would try reversing the two `script` tags shown in your code. ie put the link to thumbnailscroller before the reference to it. It's hard to see what's happening without a bit more code posted.

Comment: @El Ronnoco: I would to, but it doesn't matter; the `load` event doesn't happen until all scripts have been loaded.

Comment: The problem is your loaded code is not evaluating. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889967/jquery-load-call-doesnt-execute-javascript-in-loaded-html-file

Answer (score 1):

Because you use $(window).load(...), it's happen your **browser** load finish a page. But you load page into div by jQuery. It can't trigger load event. So you must call ThumbnailScroller function manually after loading page into div.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.thumbnailScroller.js"></script><script>/*load page into div*/ ThumbnailScroller("tsv_container","vertical",40,800,"easeOutCirc",0.4,500);</script>

Comment: Could youy send your full sample to me? takira0922@gmail.com

Comment: Yes! I recived. But you didn't say your $(window).load(...) used in which file. And which file you wanna load to div? Give me info, thanks.

Comment: in the index file, you will see im loading 2 different pages into a div. If you were to test all the 3 html pages individually, you would see that 2 of those pages(_page3.html, _page4.html) work differently than when loaded into index.html. Im trying to get them to work the same way when they are loaded into #MainWrapper in the index.html file

Comment: hey erinus, you never replied to my email

Comment: Sorry! I test for a long time. I solve problem of _page4.html. It need you edit the index.htm(line 58). Change '<div id="MainWrapper">hey</div>' to '<div id="MainWrapper" style="width:100%">hey</div>'. Because MainWrapper has no enough horizontal space, your fourth block(gray) and fifth block(dark) will arrange down straightly. And the problem of _Page3.html is so strange, I'll keep solving it.

Comment: BTW, your question isn't your problem. When _page4.htm load into div will show differently, it is caused by ContentFlow.js, not ThumbnailScroller.js

Answer (score 0):

put this line at the top

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.thumbnailScroller.js"></script>
```

something like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.thumbnailScroller.js"></script>

<script>
$(window).load(function() {

 ThumbnailScroller("tsv_container","vertical",40,800,"easeOutCirc",0.4,500);
});
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter, the OP isn't *using* the thumbnail scroller stuff until the `load` event on `window.`