# Can I make a jQuery AJAX call that parses script tags in the response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'd like HTML loaded via `$.ajax` to parse and render the `<script>` elements inside -- is this possible?

Edit: here's an example:

Response from server:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>...</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello, World!</p>
    <script>
      alert('Hey!');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I need to ensure that the `<script>` fires.

Comment: What is the content that you are trying to load? Looking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889967/jquery-load-call-doesnt-execute-javascript-in-loaded-html-file) seems that if you put `html` and `head` tags the script will not execute.

Comment: what do you want to do with the data that is not a `<script>`?

Comment: The resource I'm calling will return HTML content that may or may not have `<script>` tags in them. By default, it looks as though jQuery strips those `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe it's possible. You would need to pull out the `src` attributes of each `script` and append them to the document, where they would be rendered as they were loaded.

Comment: Yes, but could you clarify why you're trying to do what you're trying to do? It might be easier to just attach a script to the document than to load, parse, and execute something you grabbed asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax() call specify a success callback that can display html as specified in the jquery.ajax() documantation:
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});