# Making a <script> work as soon as it is appended to body?

Tags: javascript, ajax, append

This is what I have...

```
a= document.createElement('div');
a.innerHTML="<script>alert(1)</script>";
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

The `alert(1)` doesnt get executed.

@rocket @m90 i know that, but i can't use that method because i have a lot of other tags. Basically, I'm getting a webpage from ajax, striping off head tags, and embedding it into the document. Now the ajax data also has some script tags which i want to execute...

Comment: Maybe you have already seen this, but maybe not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889967/jquery-load-call-doesnt-execute-javascript-in-loaded-html-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `<script>` tags inside of `.innerHTML`. Instead you can just create a new `script` element and do it just like this:

```
a = document.createElement('script');
a.textContent = "alert('1');" ;
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the script element too:

```
var a = document.createElement('div'),
    b = document.createElement('script');
b.textContent = 'alert(1)';
a.appendChild(b);
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you have `"</script>"` in your script, the JavaScript interpreter sees this as the end of your script block. even though it is quoted.

Use:  `a.innerHTML="<script>alert(1)</sc" + "ript>";`

Comment: You're absolutely correct, but even with your improvement, it still fails to execute correctly.