# Getting div from other page and keeping <script>

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-selectors

On this asp.net site I'm working on, I want the pages to be more dynamic and less jump from page to page. I have this code;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('body').append('<div id="modalPopupOverlay"></div><div id="modalPopup"></div>');

   $("a.showInModal").click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var url = $(this).attr("href");
       $('#modalPopup').load(url+" #content");
       $('#modalPopup').show();
       $('#modalPopupOverlay').show();
   });
};)
```

This fetches the **#content** from the links page, and displays it in my popup, which is exactly like I want it.

The problem comes when the linked page contains a **script**,(which they do sometimes, tag-boxes and whatsnots) since the jquery .load drops all script-tags.

Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

try [`jQuery.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) method which loads and executes the js files.

Comment: Which of course would work, but I would prefer something that can execute the inline script-elements.

Comment: @oBusk check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889967/jquery-load-call-doesnt-execute-javascript-in-loaded-html-file