# How do I use load () to load a HTML page and JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load

At the moment I have a HTML where files can be dynamically loaded.

I am using the load() function. Within the loaded HTML file, there is an external script that I would like to execute, but it won't execute? The script will execute if I go to the HTML document directy, but not when I am using the load function.

Here is my code:

**Index Page**

```
$(".pages").load("page1.html");
```

**page1.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="alert.js"></script>
<h1>Welcome to page one</h1>
```

**Alert.js**

```
alert("This page has loaded");
```

I can confirm the rest of page1.html appears, just the javascript file won't

Help will be appreciated guys!

Thanks
Peter

Comment: Can you confirm `page1.html` is loading `alert.js` correctly?  Check the Network console in your browser to make sure it's coming back with a status 200.  Well, make sure it isn't a 4xx or 5xx code.

Comment: Look that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889967/jquery-load-call-doesnt-execute-javascript-in-loaded-html-file

Comment: It is loading correctly if I went to mysite.com/page1.html. It doesn't load it when I use the load() function with jQuery.

Comment: @Mate the reason why his script wasn't working was because he has the head tags in his external html doc,  I don't

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console? It might be a path issue, path to the JS file should be valid from the containing page

Comment: Mope, my console is clean before and after loading the file. All files share the one directory so it can't be a path issue