# jQuery Loads .aspx Page But Doesn't Execute the Script Inside

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

i'm trying to load `.aspx` page using jquery like this;

```
        $('ul#menu li ul.collapse').on('click', 'li a', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var div = $('#content .container-fluid .row-fluid .span12');

            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            setTimeout(function () {
                var htmlPage = div.load(url + ' #MainContentHolder',
                    function () {
                         //other stuff
                    });
            }, 1000);

        });
```

However, my `.aspx` page does have javascript embedded like this;

```
<div id="MainContentHolder">
    <h1>Test Aspx Content</h1>
    <div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("hello");
        </script>
    </div>
</div
```

When, i see the resulted `HTML`, i can see the it is loaded (using firebug). But it's not showing the `alert()` message 
I have also read all other questions on `stackoverflow` but it's not helpful on this to me;


### UPDATE:

 As suggested in asnwer, following code only works for the first time. I tried to turn off the `cache:false` and also tried from `GET` to `POST`;

```
 $.ajax({
         url:url,
         success:function(data){
         div.html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: load the aspx using `$.ajax` and then use `$.html` to insert the result. `$.html` will execute embedded scripts

Comment: @Aristos, yes you are right but i want that script should be executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('ul#menu li ul.collapse').on('click', 'li a', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var div = $('#content .container-fluid .row-fluid .span12');

            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $.ajax({
                        url:url,
                        success:function(data){
                                    div.html(data);
                                    //other stuff
                                }
                        });  

            }, 1000);

        });
```

Comment: the script is executed now but it's not filtering the `#MainContentHolder`. It returns the whole page. However, i want just a `Div` inside the page which is name as `MainContentHolder`

Comment: @DotNet Dreamer: for better performance, the server should return only what is needed and we don't need to filter it on client side

Comment: i tried your updated code. it's not appending the html. i did `alert(MainContentHolder)` and i m getting `object object`

Comment: ok, dear, thanks for the performance tip. I just `stripped` out the things that i didn't need and then tried your code. But the previous code worked, please update back your answer and please also remove the filtering code

Comment: @DotNet Dreamer: if you stripped out your unneccesary things. You can reuse your `load` method without selector. Like this: `var htmlPage = div.load(url,function(){});`

Comment: one more question. why this code works for the first time. i mean i don't see the `alert()` message for the second time when i clicked

Comment: @DotNet Dreamer: check if the browser caches the response (if you're using IE, it's very likely)

Comment: @DotNet Dreamer: open your browser built-in network capture to ensure that the response is 200 (not 304)

Comment: yeah, i tried it 2 times and it's returning `200` code (using google chrome)

Comment: @DotNet Dreamer: I did not run into this problem before. But my best guess is `$.html` detects the same html string and does nothing. Try `div.html("");` and then `div.html(data);`

Comment: the html is loading but the script isn't working. i typed there `alert()` and i'm not getting alert() for the second time. However, i'm getting the html;

Comment: Did you try `div.html("");` and then `div.html(data);` ? @DotNet Dreamer

Answer (score 1):

> var htmlPage = div.load(url + ' #MainContentHolder',
>                       function () {
>                            //other stuff
>                       });

As per the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) of .load(),

> If .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL,
>   however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated,
>   and thus are not executed.

Instead you may want to take your script in js file and use [$.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/), which will load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.

**Edit:**

Alternate way is to have only script in your page and load that page as shown in below link

[jQuery .load() call doesn't execute javascript in loaded html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889967/jquery-load-call-doesnt-execute-javascript-in-loaded-html-file)

OR

As already suggested use $.ajax() and in success callback function, you need explicitly execute your JS code as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7330106/309395) post. Use eval.

OR

You can load your dynamic page using .load and in success callback function use $.getScript as already suggested earlier.

I hope it helps!

Comment: i cant use `$.getScript()` becuase, as soon as the page is loaded, i want the script to be executed (which are inside that page). The pages are dynamic