# How to parse javascript/jquery to echo / execute within/after ajax result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Ajax returns all expected html result from php code, except the javacript and jQuery inside the "script" tags

```
 var frm = $('#cell');
    frm.submit(function (ev) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (html) {

    //Create jQuery object from the response HTML.
    var $return=$(html);
    //Query the jQuery object for the values
    var oneval = $return.filter('#cellWidthSlider').html();
    alert(oneval);

                $("#cellWidthDiv").html(oneval);

            }
        });

        ev.preventDefault();
    });
```

I have tried to append to head, but the jQuery code would execute only - before the elements.

```
var $response=$(html);

$("head").append($response);

var oneval = $response.filter('#cellWidthSlider').html();
```

Comment: `"but the jQuery code would execute only - after the elements."` Please explain what you mean, this question is not clear

Comment: I am echoing slider with jquery in my php script that is being processed, inside <script></script>, there is some values being extracted from database which is why the <script> have to be echoed from php...

Comment: sorry, I've typed after ...should have been before...

Comment: Why you don't use some values from database sent as json? And after ajax callback you can call your slider or do anything else with received values

Comment: Panoptik, could you give an example. I need 3 values passed to js code, how would I do it with json?

Comment: Your answer probably is here 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889967/jquery-load-call-doesnt-execute-javascript-in-loaded-html-file][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889967/jquery-load-call-doesnt-execute-javascript-in-loaded-html-file

Comment: I don't see how those questions are related - I need to load my script after html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I've been afraid of JSON, it was actually much simpler than I thought and it really took me only around 3 hours to get the general understanding, feeling good, now so so much started to look familiar in ajax and jQuery:)

So The changes I've done...
Instead of generating js within external php I have created array with values e.g.:

```
$result = array(
                array(
                       'prevCellId' => $prevCellId,
                       'prevCellWidth' => $prevCellWidth,
                       'thisCellId' => $latestCellId,
                       'thisWidth'=>$thisWidth,
                       'thisRowId' => $thisRowId,
                       'thisRowOrder' => $thisRowOrder,
                       'maxWidth' => $maxWidth,
                       'prevCellRowOrder' => $prevCellRowOrder));

echo json_encode($result);
```

Then, after long search I've managed to implement json values in my jQuery function:

```
    $.getJSON( "cellWidth.php", function( json ) {
                   $.each(json, function(i, item) {
                   $('#slider').slider({ max:''+item.maxWidth+'',min: 10,step: 5, value:''+item.thisWidth+'', slide: handleSliderChange,   stop: sendNew});
                   var $slider = $("#slider").slider({ max:''+item.maxWidth+'',min: 10,step: 5, value:''+item.thisWidth+''});
                   })
 })
```

So simply used keyword "**item.**" + "**names of arrays**" to "echo" / "use values" within jQuery - in this case this is a jQuery **slider** :))