# <script> tags not working following jQuery post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am having a problem with jQuery where by it is not loading inside a requested div.

Setup:

1. On index.php I have 4 Morris charts on 4 tabs all working fine.
2. On each tab there is a list.  Each item in the list is a link
3. Upon clicking the link the div within the tab reloads with new data
   via post:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
   $('.click5').click(function () {
       companyId = $(this).attr('id'); 

       $.post('./ajax/donut5.php', {
           clickthrough5: $('#company5-'+companyId+' .clickthrough5').val(),
           ref_date_from5: $('#company5-'+companyId+' .ref_date_from5').val(),
           ref_date_to5: $('#company5-'+companyId+' .ref_date_to5').val()
       },
       function (data) {
           $('.donut5').html(data);
       });
   });     
   });
   ```
4. The new div contains a back button to take you back to a replica of the 1st graph but on a different page (donut1.php), for my personal ease:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
   $('.backref2').click(function () {
       companyId = $(this).attr('id'); 
       $.post('./ajax/donut1.php', {
           clickthrough6: $('#company6-'+companyId+' .clickthrough6').val(),
           ref_date_from6: $('#company6-'+companyId+' .ref_date_from6').val(),
           ref_date_to6: $('#company6-'+companyId+' .ref_date_to6').val()
       },
       function (data) {
           $('.donut5').html(data);
       });
   });     
   });
   ```
5. All this code works fine up until landing on donut1.php.
6. At this point I proceeded to pull out chunks of my hair for several hours looking through Inspect Element in Chrome to identify the issue.
7. 1 bald person later I realised the jQuery was not loading although it is correctly requested in a script tag.
8. I confirmed this by placing the following on both donut1.php and donut5.php:

   ```
   <div id="divTest1"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $("#divTest1").text("Hello, world!");
   </script>
   ```
9. donut5.php displays the output fine while donut1.php does not.
10. I then tried to load an external source and a different version using the Google snippets found [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery) but this still did not work.

Some points to note:
I currently have jquery loading in my header and footer as part of trying to work this out.
As the 2 pages donut1.php and donut5.php do not include header or footer I have manually included them both in there.  Same exact way in both files.  donut5.php works donut1.php does not.

Order is index.php > donut5.php > donut1.php and then you continue to cycle between donut5 and donut 1 - or you would if the post on click was working in donut1.php.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: donut1.php:

```
<?php
include("../../../includes/config.php");

$selected = $_POST['clickthrough6'];
$date_from = $_POST['ref_date_from6'];
$date_to = $_POST['ref_date_to6'];

?>
    <script src="../../../js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.click7').click(function () {
        companyId = $(this).attr('id'); 

        $.post('./ajax/donut5.php', {
            clickthrough5: $('#company7-'+companyId+' .clickthrough7').val(),
            ref_date_from5: $('#company7-'+companyId+' .ref_date_from7').val(),
            ref_date_to5: $('#company7-'+companyId+' .ref_date_to7').val()
        },
        function (data) {
            $('.donut5').html(data);
        });
    });     
});


</script>

<div id="tabs2">
    <div id="tabs-1" class="donut5">

            <h4>Top 5 Referrers - Quotes <br /><small>Total number of Quotes between <?php echo date("d/m/Y", $date_from); ?> to <?php echo date("d/m/Y", $date_to); ?></small></h4>

        <div class="statgrid">

<div id="divTest1"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#divTest1").text("Hello, world!");
</script>

            <?php $quotes_q="SELECT 
            c.case_id,
            co.name AS company_name, 
            co.company_id AS company_id,
            COUNT(c.case_id) 'quote_count' 
            FROM 
            (`case` c,
            `panel_company` pc,
            `panel` p)
            LEFT JOIN company co ON (co.company_id = pc.company_id) 
            WHERE pc.panel_id = " .$RegisteredUser['panel_id']. " AND
            p.company_id = pc.company_id AND
            c.panel_id = p.panel_id AND 
            c.insert_date > ".$date_from. " AND 
            c.insert_date < ".$date_to. "
            GROUP BY p.panel_id
            ORDER BY quote_count DESC, co.company_id
            LIMIT 5"; 
            $result=$mysqli->query($quotes_q); ?>

            <div class="col-2-6">
                <div id="morris-donut-chart6"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="statgrid">
            <?php while ($row=$result->fetch_array()) { ?>
            <div class="col-4-6">
            <div id="company7-<?php echo $row['company_id'];?>">
                <input type="hidden" class="ref_date_from7" value="<?php echo $date_from; ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" class="ref_date_to7" value="<?php echo $date_to; ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" class="clickthrough7" value="<?php echo $row['company_id'] ?>" />
                        <a><div id="<?php echo $row['company_id'];?>" class="click7 col-5-6"><?php echo $row['company_name']; ?></div></a>
                        <div class="col-1-6"><?php echo $row['quote_count']; ?></div>
            </div>

            </div>
            <?php } ?>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<?php
    $quotes_q = "SELECT 
            c.case_id,
            co.name AS company_name, 
            COUNT(c.case_id) 'quote_count' 
            FROM 
            (`case` c,
            `panel_company` pc,
            `panel` p)
            LEFT JOIN company co ON (co.company_id = pc.company_id) 
            WHERE pc.panel_id = ".$RegisteredUser['panel_id']." AND
            p.company_id = pc.company_id AND
            c.panel_id = p.panel_id AND 
            c.insert_date > ".$date_from." AND 
            c.insert_date < ".$date_to."
            GROUP BY p.panel_id
            ORDER BY quote_count DESC, co.company_id
            LIMIT 5";

    $result = $mysqli->query($quotes_q);    

?>
<script>
    var donut_data6 = [
    <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) { ?>
    {
            label: '<?php echo substr($row['company_name'],0,15); ?>',
            value: '<?php echo $row['quote_count']; ?>'
    },
    <?php } ?>
    ];

    var donut6 = {
        element: 'morris-donut-chart6',
        data: donut_data6,
        resize: false
        }

    donut6 = Morris.Donut(donut6)

</script>
```

EDIT2:
Not too sure if this makes a different but in Network tab I have 2 listings for jquery the initial one loaded from the header which loads 304 Not Modified and the 2nd one which loads on calling donut5.php which loads as 200 OK.  Seems that after this I cannot request jquery again perhaps?

EDIT3: in donut1.php I have removed everything except for the jquery script request and the Hello World inside the div I am trying to retrieve.  Network tab still shows that jquery is not loading.  The strange thing is I have this exact setup, minus the charts, working on the same page (different div classes of course), and this does load jquery fine.

EDIT4:  Substituted jQuery for JS as a test and not even basic stand alone JS will work, added in:

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";
</script>
```

Nothing :( - Looping in JS world

EDIT5: Suppose `<script>` is a HTML tag so looping in them too.

EDIT6: When adding console.logo(data) to the function in list item 4 above I get back the following (obviously I have excluded a lot for testing:

```
    <script src="../../../js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!--
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.click7').click(function () {
        companyId = $(this).attr('id'); 

        $.post('./ajax/donut5.php', {
            clickthrough5: $('#company7-'+companyId+' .clickthrough7').val(),
            ref_date_from5: $('#company7-'+companyId+' .ref_date_from7').val(),
            ref_date_to5: $('#company7-'+companyId+' .ref_date_to7').val()
        },
        function (data) {
            $('.donut5').html(data);
        });
    });     
});
</script>
-->

<div id="tabs2">
    <div id="tabs-1" class="donut5">

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";
</script> 

<div id="divTest1"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#divTest1").text("Hello, world!");
</script>

    </div>

</div>
```

EDIT7:

Placing code here to confirm if I have correctly inplemented KevinB's suggestion.

```
var
    contentSelector = '.donut5',
    $content = $(contentSelector),
    contentNode = $content.get(0);

var documentHtml = function (html) {
    // Prepare
    var result = String(html)
        .replace(/<\!DOCTYPE[^>]*>/i, '')
    .replace(/<(html|head|body|title|meta|script)([\s\>])/gi,'<div class="document-$1"$2')
        .replace(/<\/(html|head|body|title|meta|script)\>/gi, '</div>');

    // Return
    return $.trim(result);
};



$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.click5').click(function () {
        companyId = $(this).attr('id');

        $.post('./ajax/donut5.php', {
            clickthrough5: $('#company5-' + companyId + ' .clickthrough5').val(),
            ref_date_from5: $('#company5-' + companyId + ' .ref_date_from5').val(),
            ref_date_to5: $('#company5-' + companyId + ' .ref_date_to5').val()
        },

        function (data) {


            var
                $data = $(documentHtml(data)),
                $dataBody = $data.find('.donut5'),
                $dataContent = $dataBody.find(contentSelector),
                $menuChildren, contentHtml, $scripts;

            // Fetch the scripts
            $scripts = $dataContent.find('.document-script');
            if ($scripts.length) {
                $scripts.detach();
            }

            // Fetch the content
            contentHtml = $dataContent.html() || $data.html();
            $scripts.each(function () {
                var $script = $(this),
                    scriptText = $script.text(),
                    scriptNode = document.createElement('script');
                if ($script.attr('src')) {
                    if (!$script[0].async) {
                        scriptNode.async = false;
                    }
                    scriptNode.src = $script.attr('src');
                }
                scriptNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(scriptText));
                contentNode.appendChild(scriptNode);
            });
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
```

EDIT8:

After trying the code above in EDIT7 the `.donut5` in no longer being pulled from donut5.php to index.php which was originally working.  I can see that jquery doesn't duplicate anymore on Network tab when clicking the link for donut5.php (even though the call to it is still there).  Currently either I assume I have not mapped a div correctly above as I did remove part of the class find code for `:first` as I felt it was not required or somehow I have managed to make things worse!

Comment: Alright so `donut1.php` is called by `donut5.php` but you don't see anything returned? Perhaps the AJAX call is never reached. What does your `donut5.php` look like?

Comment: @Shahar None at all.  I have been tailing the log for hours.  To be more accurate on the index.php - index.php includes donuts.php which has the same code in yes.  That one loads perfectly fine.  It is the master file and also contains jQuery tabs and 3 other donuts, again all working fine.  It is only when you get to donut1.php where no jQuery works at all.  Not even my Hellow World test.  I have noticed that when I click the link taking my to donut5.php jQuery loads in Network but doesn't load when i click the link taking me to donut1.php.  Odd!

Comment: Seems like the error is in `index.php` then; `donut1.php` may not be called properly. Can you post `index.php`?

Comment: @Shahar.  I get data displayed on donut1.php.  My list appears perfectly.  But the donut does not and the links do not take me back again to donut5.php.  I have also echo'd all the sql and manually ran in phpmyadmin several times to ensure all data was accurate and as I expected to see it.

Comment: The only reason it wouldn't work is if you have a javascript error. Try replacing the `donut1.php`s first JS code with `$(document).ready(function () { $("#divTest1").text("Hello, world!"); });` and see if that works.

Comment: @Shahar This is really odd!  I have removed all other script tags (apart from the call for jquery.js) and it still doesn't work.  jQuery still does not load in the Network tab.  However, if I browse to donut1.php directly then jquery.js loads fine and so does the Hello World

Comment: @Shahar I have just swapped the order.  So now index.php loads donut1.php first and it works.  For some reason on the second click it refuses to load jquery

Comment: @Shahar - FYI added more info from Network Tab.

Comment: If you use `$.post` to load `donut1`, you aren't really "landing" on `donut1`. Your code in step 4 grabs the entire HTML content of `donut1.php`, and attempts to put that into your `donut5` div. Putting the entire source code of a page into a div won't work; you can't have an `html` element inside a `div`. There's an answer that describes a possible solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889967/jquery-load-call-doesnt-execute-javascript-in-loaded-html-file

Comment: @ChristianVarga Thanks Christian though this confuses me somewhat.  I am already posting and bringing back the entire contents of a div from donut5.php to index.php - This works fine.  Where it breaks down is from donut5.php > donut1.php.  These files are essentially identical.

Comment: @ChristianVarga - missed edit time window sorry - Also, still learning jquery so not sure exactly how it renders, none of the files contain the `html` tag or are you referring to the full list - as in - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/HTML5_element_list

Comment: I see, well that's not your problem then. Still, using `$.post` to load a page **does not load the referenced resources**. If it does in some particular case, then this is a bug, because it is not supposed to. Javascript is very forgiving like that. If you want to load a resource, then use `$.getScript()`. Having said all of that, **jQuery is already loaded**. So there's no reason to need to reload it. You certainly don't need to reload it after you call `$.post`. You should move all of your javascript out of the donut.php files so that you aren't reloading it every time you call `$.post`.

Comment: @ChristianVarga - Thanks Christian.  I will have a good play in the AM and let you know how I get on. :)

Comment: Awesome. I think it would be best if you could create a small self-contained html-only demo of your problem (eg, remove all those mysql queries) so that we can see it in action. At the moment it's really hard to figure out exactly where the problem lies because we still don't have the full picture and can't execute the code.

Comment: @ChristianVarga - I started doing that and completed the first page in jsfiddle with all the tabs and then I came apart trying to figure out how I could replicate a post to another page.  I may have another go tomorrow but for now I think I need to put my brain on ice.  It has had a long hard day of going round in circles!

Comment: Why are you using post just to load a page? Can't you just have a link?

Comment: @slime  I am posting data to the page and loading back the div .donut5 (not the whole page).  This is so that I can make all the content within the div dynamic.  There are several divs like this on the main index.php (or included within there) so I want it to be seamless with no reloads ect.  I need to post data to that page in order to update the entries within the div.

Comment: by reading your question it sounds like you included jquery a hundred times, what does your console output say ?

Comment: @johnSmith I have added a console.log.  Please let me know if this is not what you meant.  Thanks

Comment: Your test at #8 misses one important piece. A console.log or alert to ensure the code is running. The test you used instead will fail if it runs before the element it is targeting exists on the page (which is likely the root of this entire problem.)

Comment: Since the htmlstring you are appending is relatively complex, jQuery will convert it to a dom fragment before appending it to the DOM. This will result in the contained javascript being executed before the elements are part of the `document`, thus causing jquery selectors as well as `document.find...` to not find the elements.

Comment: One possible solution to that issue is to use regexp (this is so evil..) to change all `<script>...</script>` tags to `<textarea class="rep-script"></textarea>` tags and then eval the value of said textareas after parsing and appending the content to the page.

Comment: An example of the regexp replace can be found here: https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify/blob/master/ajaxify-html5.js

Comment: @KevinB This is a big more complex than I was expecting.  Would you be able to provide or point me to a sample of using regexp in such a case please?

Comment: haha. I keep answering your comments before you post them. :)

Comment: @KevinB haha love it!  Will have a look now and let you know! Thanks

Comment: Look for the documentHtml helper function and how it is used.

Comment: @KevinB  I have placed a sample usage of your suggestion at EDIT7.  Please can you check that this is the correct usage as I have understood it and I will implement across the other pages which are complex and give it a test run.  Thanks

Comment: Nope, you're missing the part where you detatch the scripts from the returned html. https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify/blob/master/ajaxify-html5.js#L123-L135

Comment: @KevinB Well... You wernt messing around when you said this was evil! Learn jquery I said. It will be easy I said haha!

Comment: I've only ever used this technique once, and i've never looked back. Never again will i include javascript within an html partial.

Comment: @KevinB See I though by putting the JS at the bottom of the page outside of the div `dount5` it would render the graph then pull through the div.  The other script snippets I only added to test why jquery wanst working at all which led to me noticing that jQuery was not loading in the Network Tab at all for donut1.php but was for donut5.php which had be going crazy as they are identical really.

Comment: I just woke up to this. Glad you got the solution ^_^.

Comment: @KevinB - Please can you take a look at EDIT 7 for me.  This is my interpretation.  Is this correct?

Comment: @KevinB Sorry to tie you up so much!  Have just updated further.  Thanks!

Comment: You made a modification to the documentHtml method that shouldn't have been done (using your own class) you should use the built-in one so that you can properly select the target elements later.

Comment: @KevinB - Thanks - I have set this back to `.replace(/<(html|head|body|title|meta|script)([\s\>])/gi,'<div class="document-$1"$2')` but still no joy.  I am guessing that some of my edits under `function (data) {` will be incorrect too in that case

Comment: `$dataContent.find('.donut5')` -> `$dataContent.find('.document-script')` when finding and detaching script elements.

Comment: @KevinB - I have changed that one too but still not joy.  I have reposted it as it is not with the 2 notes indicating what is now different from the original

Comment: The edit on this line probably makes the script finding part not work. `$dataContent = $dataBody`

Comment: If you don't understand what the code does, you likely shouldn't use it anyway. Take a step back and read over it, try to understand what it is doing. Maybe then you'll know what changes to make to it.

Comment: @KevinB I have had a read and from what I understand the code you shared with my looks for and alters styling based on selection.  Looks like quite a nice all in 1 solution actually. Obviously though I have no :first so I thought I could set the filter back to the previous variable - have set this now to `$dataBody.find('.donut5'),` which looking through the code looks like I can remove `$dataBody`.  Like you say, I probably wont be coming anywhere near this again.  But it has got to the stage now where I MUST BEAT IT! hahaha.

Comment: Understood. Look at it this way. What you have is a string, and your goal is to convert that string to a dom fragment without parsing any of the included javascript. That's why the script tags are replaced with divs. Step two is to detach those divs from the fragment, append the fragment to the DOM, and then execute the scripts.

Comment: *"Is that what the last part of the code attempts to achieve by way of document.createElement"* Yes, though i don't see where you defined `contentNode`

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an htmlstring to .html, one of two things happen. It either gets inserted using `.innerHTML`, or it gets inserted using `.empty().append(htmlString)`. Which one is chosen is based on the complexity of the htmlstring passed in.

If it's relatively simple, .innerHTML will be used and scripts will execute in the way you expected.

However, if it is more complex, the elements are first parsed and appended to a docFragment before being appended to the document. This middle step is what causes your problem because the javascript will be executed before the elements are part of `document`.

The only way to fix this issue is to forcibly delay the execution of the javascript by either coding the javascript in such a way that it's execution is in a callback that later gets called, or by removing the javascript from the htmlstring before appending it and then executing it after.

Below is an example of the former:

```
(function divTestLooper () {
    if (!$("#divTest1").length) {
        // the element didn't exist, lets wait a little longer...
        return setTimeout(divTestLooper, 10);
    }
    $("#divTest1").text("Hello, world!");
})();
```

Here is an example of the latter:
https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify/blob/master/ajaxify-html5.js#L60-L70
and
https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify/blob/master/ajaxify-html5.js#L123-L135
and
https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify/blob/master/ajaxify-html5.js#L158-L167

---

Of course, the best solution is likely to avoid this problem entirely by not including javascript in your partials.

Comment: Out of curiosity is there a way to identify which method is being used `.innerHTML` or `.empty().append(htmlString)`

Comment: Here is where it happens in the src: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L423-L437 If it throws an exception, it falls back to the method that causes your problem. Though, i'm not sure what would cause an exception in that area, haven't researched it that far.

Comment: Thanks Kevin!  I might tweak my jquery.js to console an alert there for future reference.  Just working on the extra code snippets I missed (well, getting my head round them).  Will let you know how I do