# External file script is not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Iam using load() for loading external html file.

```
$("#header_section").load("header.html");
$("#sidemenu_section").load("side_menu.html");
```

Here, HTML file is loaded and css also loaded but  script file is not loading in the page

```
<script src="js/utility.js"></script>
```

I tried to declare the above script file inside the head and inside the body. Both are not working.

Comment: Are you sure js/utility.js exists? Do you see any console logs indicating a 404 or similar error?

Comment: There is no error and files also exists. But that files are loaded in html page

Comment: link to js file is inside header.html ?

Comment: This files is used for partcular page only. not for all page. Thats y i given in another html file not in header.html

Comment: Can you bebug and check whether .js is loading or not.

Comment: I have debuged. Loaded external pages's css only added. JS not added

Comment: try adding jquery after the end of </body> also check whether or not jquery library are added.

Comment: Did you check the sources. js file must display

Comment: I have added jquery even inside the body also. onReady event is working. and external file also loaded including css. but js?..

Comment: In sources, js files are not there

Comment: This might will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889967/jquery-load-call-doesnt-execute-javascript-in-loaded-html-file

Comment: Can you show us the content of utility.js ?

Answer (score 2):

Check your relative path to the  utility.js file and make sure to load juery.js library before load utility.js file.

and finally try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/utility.js"></script>
```

to load the utility.js file.

Comment: Good job on the relative to absolute path resolution!

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to add jquery.min.js file. use below code.

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/utility.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: I have added jquery. Without jquery, we cannot use load(). Problem is load() is working, external script is not including

Comment: I think you are using secure server(https). then external file will not load then you need to download external file on your server.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery may only execute your code with the type attribute set to "text/javascript", per this bug filed a long time ago:

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3733

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://your.cdn.com/first.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
loadScript("http://your.cdn.com/second.js", function(){
    //initialization code
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery code that adds HTML to the DOM always strips out `<script>` tags. It runs them and then throws them away.

An exception to that behavior is when you use "$.load()" with the hack that allows you to load a fragment of a page:

```
$.load("http://something.com/whatever #stuff_I_want", function() { ... });
```

In that case, the scripts are stripped and not evaluated/run.