# Script after Jquery .load doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I'm using jquery to load a new html page inside my div (curso), but the link have other jquery function that plays when my page loads. The problem is: since I create the html inside my div, the internal function can't work.

My script in first page:

```
$("#loginsb").click(function () { 

$("#curso").load("primeiro/index.html");

});
```

My script (working if I open the window) in the div internal html:

```
$(window).bind('load', function(){...
```

Is there anyone here to tell me how can I play the internal script when the page is fully load on my div?

Thanks!

Comment: is this what you're looking for ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889967/jquery-load-call-doesnt-execute-javascript-in-loaded-html-file

Comment: Thank you, Juan! After Removing the tags the script still paused. Any other idea?