# Inject external HTML & JS into a page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build some small widgets tools that webmasters can embed in their websites.

Is there any way that the webmaster can simply load this tool by including a script like this?

```
<script src="http://mysite/widget.js"></script>
```

I tried to inject it by loading it in AJAX and then do an `appendChild()` on the body, it's working this way but the JS is not executed.

Content to be injected:

```
<div>one div</div>
<script>alert('some js')</script>
```

widget.js

```
function load(content) {
  var $body = document.body,
      $div = document.createElement("div");
  $div.id = "widget";
  $div.innerHTML = content; 
  $body.appendChild($div);
}
```

The content variable contains HTML and JS but the JS is not executed when injected.

Comment: Can you post your `content` html code part which contain js

Comment: @Armen i edited  the question

Comment: Lot of good solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889967/jquery-load-call-doesnt-execute-javascript-in-loaded-html-file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you don't know where you script will be added - to the head or body tag - and consequently when it will be executed, you need to make sure that DOM is ready, so:

```
 function load(content) {

    if (document.readyState === "complete" || document.readyState === "loaded") {
         // manipulate DOM
    } else {
       document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        // manipulate DOM
    })
}
```

Also, since scripts elements added using `innerHTML` don't get executed, you'd have to either use `eval` or better create a script like that:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.text = "alert(\"hi\");"
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
```

However, there is no point to add `<script>` tag to execute some script in your template, since your script is already running when you're adding DOM so do all necessary setups there.

Comment: looks good but the script i show is just an example, in real it's much more complicate than alert(). The js i want to load depend on which template widget i load. that's why i make it all in one generated by a php file.

You mean i have to load the script and the html separately ?

Comment: what I'm saying is that your `widget.js` should be split into `js` and `html` parts (templates). initialize js part of your widget using the code inside `widget.js`, not code inside `<script>` tags of templates, because it doesn't make sense to have it there. If you still want to have your code inside `<script>` tags, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20584396/2545680) which shows the recursive function that replaces all occurrences of `<script>` tag with `createElement('script')`.

Comment: To use `eval` just pass `js` as a string `eval('alert("hello")')`. However, `eval()` is not a good option since it won't get executed under strict [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/Using_Content_Security_Policy). Also, you'd still have to have separate `js` and `html` code since `eval` can't work reliably work with `html`

Comment: so i will have to do 2 request to the server ? on for the html template and one for the js script right ?

Comment: no, just put `js` into `widget.js`, and store templates in variables inside `js`. you can start working on it and then ask another question with specifics and link it here

Comment: using your solution i'm trying to find a clean way to store my template html in the javascript file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40742552/encode-and-pass-html-from-php-to-javascript/40743294 

is it ok to have a <script> tag in my js file holding my template ?

Comment: Warning! `document.createElement('script')` will be set `async` to `true` by default. It may cause a problem if first js file is large, slow loading but second js file is load faster and depend on first js file.

Answer (score 3):

### UPDATE

please see Maximus' answer.

---

Right, the default native innerHTML doesn't execute js for safe sake.

jQuery or zepto $.fn.append() can satisfy your need, here is the reason (from zepto source code)

```
if (el.nodeName != null && el.nodeName.toUpperCase() === 'SCRIPT' &&
           (!el.type || el.type === 'text/javascript') && !el.src)
          window['eval'].call(window, el.innerHTML)
```

You can see in the function $.fn.append it will see if it's a script, if so it will use `eval` to run the content. You may need `eval` to, but be careful since some webmasters may deliver 'vice' code

Comment: where is OP using `appendChild` to execute script?

Comment: I think OP wants to get `<script>alert('some js ')</script>` executed by appendChild

Comment: ok, sorry, missed that. actually, it's not `appendChild` doesn't execute scripts, it's `<scripts`> added with `innerHTML` don't get executed. `appendChild` can do it. See my answer.

Comment: @Maximus, vote up you are right, thank you for pointing my mistake, both native appendChild function or window.eval works.