# Encode and pass HTML from PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

i need to pass an html template to a javascript variable in php

i tried differents things like json_encode(), str_replace() addcslashes() but javascript always throw an error of unexpected character

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('template.html');

function escapeJavaScriptText($string)
{
    return str_replace("\n", '\n', str_replace('"', '\"',      addcslashes(str_replace("\r", '', (string)$string), "\0..\37'\\")));
}
?>

<script> var template = "<?php echo escapeJavaScriptText($html)  ?>"</script>
```

Comment: You can try  str_replace (array("\r\n", "\n", "\r"), ' ', $html). 
But are you sure it's best solution? to pass an html template to a javascript variable in PHP ;)?

Comment: i'm not sure :D but i need my html template and my js in the same js file

Comment: yes, sorry this is just an error in the example

Answer (score 1):

I always use a `<script>` tag to hold my HTML templates. It's a habit I learned from using Handlebars JS. http://handlebarsjs.com/

The trick is the `type="text/html"` attribute, the browser doesn't know what do with it so it doesn't display it and doesn't try to run it as code.

```
<script type="text/html" id="Template1">
    <p>This is a template</p>
    <p>More template stuff</p>
</script>
```

To access the template you can do something like

JQuery:

```
$('#Template1').html()
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('Template1').innerHTML;
```

Comment: looks good, is it ok to put multiple <script> tags in the same .js file ?

Comment: @TheShun I don't see why you couldn't, but I've only ever done it with one.

Comment: i just tried, i can't use this method since my script is a .js file already embeded in a script src tag