# Linked script won't apply to the loaded HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I'm linking a javascript file on my page like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="example.js"></script>
```

I have some HTML elements loaded normally and at the same time I'm loading `HTML` content from another page like this with the same elements:

```
$( "#loaded_data-1" ).load( "Curriculum2.htm .half" , function( response, status, xhr ) {
        // but this content won't access example.js so I need to call it like this below.
$.getScript( "example.js");         
});
```

but this loaded content won't access example.js so I need to call through `$.getScript( "example.js");`.

But this causes problems for the original normally loaded elements because for them it is loaded twice. How do I load `example.js` once and apply to the all items on my site loaded the regular way and loaded with `ajax`?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's a [duplicate problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889967/jquery-load-call-doesnt-execute-javascript-in-loaded-html-file).

You can also use $.loadScript as follows:

```
$.loadScript('url_to_someScript.js', function(){
    //Do after someScript has loaded
}
```

Comment: It is not a duplicate. I already saw that question. From the script you can see I'm not loading the entire HTML page only certain parts.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your `script` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="example.js"></script>
```

Just add the script -- using your `$.getScript()` method -- once all of your HTML elements have been loaded. That way, the JavaScript won't be applied until all of your HTML elements are present and accounted for.

Comment: sorry that's not an option. I can't remove that because the first normally loaded elements won't work until the rest is loaded.

Comment: Ah, okay. Is `example.js` your file? If so, maybe you could break it up into two scripts -- one to call right away, and another with code for the dynamic HTML elements added later.