# Why this function stops working when I load the script inside a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the "plyr.js" video player script. All works perfectly when I open the page on its own, but when I load it inside a div of another (i.e. when I load video.html inside a div of my index.html), the function stops working...

Any idea on how to solve it?

This is the code:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.plyr.io/3.4.6/plyr.css'>

<video class="video-fluid" id="player" poster="fotos/demo1.jpg" playsinline autoplay loop>
  <source src="demo1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<button type="button" class="btn js-stop" id="stop">Stop</button>


<script src='https://cdn.plyr.io/3.4.6/plyr.js'></script>
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {    
      controls = [];
      player = new Plyr('#player', { controls });
      window.player = player;
    });
    $("#stop").click(function(){
      player.stop();
    });
</script>
```

As I mentioned, the code on its own works perfectly, but when I load it inside a div of another page with a .load("video.html"), the stop button no longer works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What debugging steps have you taken? Are there any console errors? Is `player` instantiated when you click the stop button?

Comment: you need to move the script into the callback function of the `.load`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery .load() call doesn't execute JavaScript in loaded HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889967/jquery-load-call-doesnt-execute-javascript-in-loaded-html-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attach event to dynamic elements in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896106/attach-event-to-dynamic-elements-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MDN: DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded):

> The DOMContentLoaded event fires when the **initial** HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.

So the `DOMContentLoaded` does only fire once, and the event will fire before the html that is loaded using `.load("video.html")` is added to the to the DOM, so the `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',` would not have any effect if it was added in the `video.html`.

I acutely don't see why you need that `DOMContentLoaded` event listener in that case.

If you write:

```
<video class="video-fluid" id="player" poster="fotos/demo1.jpg" playsinline autoplay loop>
  <source src="demo1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<button type="button" class="btn js-stop" id="stop">Stop</button>


<script src='https://cdn.plyr.io/3.4.6/plyr.js'></script>
<script>
    // document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {    
      controls = [];
      player = new Plyr('#player', { controls });
      window.player = player;
    // });
    $("#stop").click(function(){
      player.stop();
    });
</script>
```

Then `new Plyr` should still find that element, because the element is added to the DOM before the script is executed.

Comment: Thank you a lot! that solved the problem! I was using that code because I downloaded an example of the "plyr.js" usage and it was working perfectly as it was written till now.... Thanks again!